# iOS - Swift - Screen Resizes on App Start

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am working on an iOS application using Swift.  Recently whenever I run the application it no longer fills the screen.  There are black bars on the top and bottom.  The weird thing is that the status/notification bar also shrinks down.  The same thing happens on the simulators so it doesn't seem to be my device.  Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Joe are you using autolayout at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Xcode 6 & Swift: Black bars appear above and below the viewcontroller on iOS 7 iPhone 5 device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26084819/xcode-6-swift-black-bars-appear-above-and-below-the-viewcontroller-on-ios-7-i)

Someone has a very similar problem, it seems they solved it by changing the size of their launchscreen.xib. Without seeing code its difficult to say what your problem is though

Comment: Thanks, that did end up helping.  I tried having my Default (Launch) images in a deeper directory.  Once I moved them back out to the project root it fixed things.